# Вопрос по времени жизни сессии PHP

Tags: сессия, php

Есть несколько скриптов

1.php

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 10);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 10);
session_set_cookie_params(10));

session_start();
$_SESSION['studentid']=$_POST['studentid'];
?>
//html <form> на 2.php
```

2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['studentid'])) {
    echo 'no id';
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Если я зайду на 1.пхп и подожду >10 секунд и подтвержу форму ссылающуюся на 2.php, там условие с $_SESSION['studentid'] не сработает, а в var_dump($_SESSION); будет видно что $_SESSION['studentid'] все еще жива и сессия все еще находится в памяти. Хотя я же явно перед стартом сессии ввел 10 секунд всеми знакомыми мне способами. Почему так происходит?
Мне нужно что бы если юзер сидит больше 10 секунд на 1.пхп, то в 2.пхп уже не было его $_SESSION['studentid'] там.

Comment: session.gc_maxlifetime весьма не простой параметр, это время после которого **разрешено** удалять файл сессии, удалялка запускается в зависимост от параметров session.gc_probability и session.gc_divisor i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а может вам сделать по другому?

в файле 1.php создаете переменню сессии с меткой времени, а в файле 2.php проверяете разницу между текущим временм и с меткой времени в сессии - и тут уже делаете свою логику)